# Outlook 2010 hide sent items that show on my BCC

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to hide BCC in the sent items for Outlook 2010. I am using an auto BCC script.

So while sending i can't see that BCC is going to the HOD, but if I double click on the sent items it shows BCC. Is there a way to hide it? Or may be if I can modify the script to hide the address.

Script used

```
x--------------------------------x----...
Dim objRecip As Recipient 
Dim strMsg As String 
Dim res As Integer 
Dim strBcc As String 
On Error Resume Next 

' #### USER OPTIONS #### 
' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable 
' to a name in the address book 
strBcc = "someone@email.com" 

Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc) 
objRecip.Type = olBCC 
If Not objRecip.Resolve Then 
strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _ 
"Do you want still to send the message?" 
res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _ 
"Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient") 
If res = vbNo Then 
Cancel = True 
End If 
End If 

Set objRecip = Nothing
```

Comment: May I know why do you need that? BCC is shown for you only. Even administrators with full access permissions on your mailbox can't see it.

Comment: I agree with thims, you can't remove the BCC unless you modify the email message on the server/your computer (don't do this, Outlook won't like that). The only person who can see it is you, and I don't see why you'd want to hide this from yourself, since you obviously already know it's happening.